# possible to cast this Alamofire result to an array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, alamofire

I am not an iOS dev and have to make a few changes to a Swift / AlamoFire project (not mine) and am a bit lost.

I have the following JSON:

```
{"metro_locations":
 [
   {
     "name":"Ruby Red"
   },
   {
      "name":"Blue Ocean"
    }
  ]
}
```

class (I know that there are issues here):

```
class Location{
  var name=""
  init(obj:tmp){
    self.name=tmp["name"]
  }
}
```

and need to make an AlamoFire call

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.domain.com/arc/v1/api/metro_areas/1", parameters: nil)
  .responseJSON { response in

    if let dataFromNetworking = response.result.value {
      let metroLocations = dataFromNetworking["metro_locations"]
      var locations: [Location]=[]
      for tmp in metroLocations as! [Dictionary] { // <- not working, Generic Paramter 'Key' could not be inferred
        let location=Location.init(obj: tmp)
        locations.append(location)
      }
    }
}
```

I have included the error msg, the "not working" but feel that there are issues in other parts too (like expecting a dictionary in the initialization). What does the 'Key' could not be inferred mean and are there other changes I need to make?

#### edit #1

I have updated my Location to this to reflect your suggestion:

```
  init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    guard let id = dictionary["id"] else { return nil }
    guard let name = dictionary["name"] else { return nil }
    guard let latitude = dictionary["latitude"] else { return nil }
    guard let longitude = dictionary["longitude"] else { return nil }
    self.name = name as! String
    self.id = id as! Int
    self.latitude = latitude as! Double
    self.longitude = longitude as! Double
  }
```

but I get the error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10f387600) to 'NSNumber' (0x10f77f2a0).
```

like this:

[image]

I would think that the `guard` statement would prevent this. What am I missing?

Comment: Your `guard` statement tests if the `latitude` is missing. But your error suggests that `latitude` key was present, but the value was `null` (in the JSON; which translates to `NSNull`). You can expand the `guard` statement to capture this. Eg `guard let latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? Double else { return nil }`. And then you can lose the `as!` forced cast. Avoid forced casting unless you know it cannot fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `metroLocations` as an array of dictionaries, namely:

```
Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
```

Or, more concisely:

```
[[String: String]]
```

Thus:

```
if let dataFromNetworking = response.result.value {
    guard let metroLocations = dataFromNetworking["metro_locations"] as? [[String: String]] else {
        print("this was not an array of dictionaries where the values were all strings")
        return
    }

    var locations = [Location]()
    for dictionary in metroLocations {
        if let location = Location(dictionary: dictionary) {
            locations.append(location)
        }
    }
}
```

Where

```
class Location {
    let name: String

    init?(dictionary: [String: String]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] else { return nil }
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Clearly, I used `[[String: String]]` to represent an array of dictionaries where the values were all strings, as in your example. If the values included objects other than strings (numbers, booleans, etc.), then you might use `[[String: AnyObject]]`.

---

In your revision, you show us a more complete `Location` implementation. You should avoid `as!` forced casting, and instead us `as?` in the `guard` statements:

```
class Location {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? Double,
            let longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? Double else {
                return nil
        }
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

Comment: thx Rob, that makes sense but I have updated and extended my Location class but am getting an error with NSNull in the `edit #1` added to the original question. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: thx, awesome man! would you say that using the guard statement like this is the best pattern for JSON parsing. It seems like it effectively is validating for the presence of the four values and returning nil if any of the four are not  nil. Is that correct? Thx again and sorry for my uninformed questions.

Comment: It's a bit of a stylistic preference, but, IMHO, `guard let` statements are perfect for validating data. But you can achieve something similar with `if let` syntax, too, if you really want. You can get away with either in this fairly simple case, though I think `guard` makes your intent clear. There are other advantages to `guard`, too (e.g. it will warn you if your `else` clause fails to exit properly), but, like I said, you can accomplish something similar with `if let` if you're not yet comfortable with `guard let`.