# optional / safe loading in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, option-type

**My Program's Flow**

I have a Class called News Item. in it, I have a method that goes to a server and fetches JSON Data and creates a NewsItem instance that has each of the JSON data details in a for loop using the SWIFTYJson library as follows:

```
static func downloadNewsItems(completionBlock block : ([NewsItem]) -> ()) {

var newsItems = [NewsItem]()
let url = NSURL(string: "http://a-url-that-has-stuff")
let networkService = NetworkService(url: url!)

networkService.downloadData { (data) -> Void in

  let jsonData = JSON(data:data)
  for item in jsonData["stories"].arrayValue {

    let newsArticle = NewsItem()
    newsArticle.storyCategory = item["category"].string
    newsArticle.titleText = item["title"].string
    newsArticle.paragraph1 = item["paragraph1"].string
    newsArticle.paragraph2 = item["paragraph2"].string
    newsArticle.featureImage = item["headerImage"].string
    newsArticle.storyDate = item["date"].string
    newsArticle.majorReference = item["majorReference"].string
    newsArticle.fact = item["fact"].string

    newsItems.append(newsArticle)

  }

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    block(newsItems)
  })
 }
}
```

I have a collectionViewController that calls this method, gets the objects and appends them to an array which i then use to load the collection view data.

**My Problem**

If you look at the code, at this point, every newsArticle must have all the properties of the news item for this to work. I don't like this behaviour. I'm looking at adding more properties to the NewsItem class that aren't required but if available, should be loaded and properly instantiated. For example, I want to add a second image to the News Item class but not every news item will have a second image. If I add a news item that doesn't have 'titleText' for example, to the backend, the code will break.

I want to add this second image feature, and if a news item has a 'second image', then I want to instantiate a UIImageView and add it to the collectionView with this image.

I know I'm supposed to use optionals somehow but i can't quite crack it. I'm using Swift 3. Optionals, I must admit, have been the bane of my existence since i started swift. Any help would be appreciated. Danke!

**EDIT**

I'm implementing the newsItem class as follows:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

 var newsItems = [NewsItem]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

NewsItem.downloadNewsItems{ (newsItems) -> () in

      self.newsItems = []
      self.newsItems = newsItems
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
 }
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return newsItems.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsCollectionViewCell

  let story = newsItems[indexPath.item]
  cell.configureCell(story)
  return cell

 }
}
```

The configureCell method just downloads anything that needs to be downloaded and then adds the text/images/links to the cell properties. Nothing special there.

Comment: Please post the implementation of your NewsItem class.

Comment: you're probably going to want to have an init method on newsitem that manages the optional / non-optional attributes rather than assigning them line-by-line as here.

Comment: @Max I've added the edit requested.

Comment: hmmm @timpone.... okay... so is it a thing that optionals generally won't work with this kind of setup and i always need to use an init method or is it just specific to my case going by the code sample i've provided? And would you mind showing me an implementation of such? thanks for the answer.

Comment: I find how to instantiate with optionals a bit confusing and had to update some code that someone else wrote. I asked this question and answer which MIGHT help (or might not) but I think is a start in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980047/how-to-make-an-attribute-in-the-following-call-optional-ie-allow-nil   and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956463/possible-to-cast-this-alamofire-result-to-an-array-of-dictionaries

Comment: @timpone been looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980047/how-to-make-an-attribute-in-the-following-call-optional-ie-allow-nil and the accepted answer trying to implement an init method in my newsItem class and i'm hitting a brick wall. When I add an init method to the class, is there a way to create an instance of the class without using the init?

Comment: @MwiTi - like calling var item = NewsItem() ? Adding an init method might preclude that - I'm not 100% sure. Passing a dictionary to the init method is a pretty well-established pattern but if you want to do a different way, feel free.

Comment: @timpone so I've overridden the init() method alongside my custom init(dictionary: [[String:AnyObject]]) and it works as I wanted... Still haven't solved the problem in the OP though.